# Variable shows the wrong date

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a query where I want the youngest date from a column containing a assetID. It works very well. But when i print it out, it shows a complete different date.

tried fetchone, fetchall nothing worked.

```
cursorObj.execute('SELECT max(date) from assetsvalues where assetid =3')
output = cursorObj.fetchone()
print(output)
```

Results are:

```
2019-11-10
('2019-11-01',)
```

The first line is right, but why is there a completely different date when I print the output?

Comment: Provide a table definition and sample data (preferably as create table and insert statements for easy testing) and your expected results from that sample.

Comment: You have a single `print` statement but two lines of output. Where's the other line coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Ok ive found the error:
I ve had print (today) in the first line of my code, and 2019-11-01 is the right answer. Sorry for your time guys, but ive spend hours and didnt saw it...